# I want to update my website on github using different machine

Tags: git, github, hosting

I use github to host my static portfolio website, I changed a laptop and I now want to edit some features in the website, I already make the changes on my PC. So how can I update d only changes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How did you change your laptop?   If you are already making changes on your PC, what else do you need?   (Is your PC different than your laptop?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to git clone your repository on GitHub or use the commande `git pull`

Comment: I use the previous code I saved on a flash drive, I edited it can it work?